# Problema com o DOMPDF

Tags: php, html

Eu possuo o seguinte formulário :

```
<div >

    <form id="form" action="laudo_solicitacao_completo.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>

            <label class="ui-corner-bl ui-corner-tr" for="numeroCNES" >Número do CNES</label>
            <input id="numeroCNES" name="CNES"> <br>

            <label for="estabelecimentoSolicitante">Nome do estabelecimento de saúde solicitante</label>
            <input id="estabelecimentoSolicitante" name="estabelecimentoSolicitante"> <br>

            <label for="nomeCompletoDoPaciente">Nome completo do paciente</label>
            <input id="nomeCompletoDoPaciente" name="nomeCompletoDoPaciente"> <br>

            <label for="nascimentoDoPaciente">Nascimento</label>
            <input type="date" id="nascimentoDoPaciente" name="nascimentoDoPaciente"> <br>

            <label for="enderecoPaciente">Endereço paciente</label>
            <input id="enderecoPaciente" name="enderecoPaciente"> <br>

            <label for="nomeDaMae">Nome da mãe do paciente</label>
            <input id="nomeDaMae" name="nomeDaMae"> <br>

            <label for="pesoDoPaciente">Peso do paciente</label>
            <input id="pesoDoPaciente" name="pesoDoPaciente"> <br>

            <label for="alturaPaciente">Altura do paciente</label>
            <input id="alturaPaciente" name="alturaPaciente"> <br>

            <hr>

            <label for="medicamentoUm">Medicamento 01</label>
            <input id="medicamentoUm" name="medicamentoUm"> <br>

            <label for="quant">Quantidade solicitada para o mês um : </label>
            <input id="quantidadeUm" name="quantSolMesUm"> <br>

            <label for="quantSolMesDois">Quantidade solicitada para o mês dois : </label>
            <input id="quantidadeDois" name="quantSolMesDois"> <br>

            <label for="quantSolMesTres">Quantidade solicitada para o mês tres : </label>
            <input id="quantidadeTres" name="quantSolMesTres"> <br>

            <hr>

            <label for="medicamentoDois">Medicamento 02</label>
            <input name="medicamentoDois" name="medicamentoDois"> <br>

            <label for="mesUm">Quantidade solicitada para o mês um</label>
            <input id="quantidadeQuatro" name="mesUm"> <br>

            <label for="mesDois">Quantidade solicitada para o mês dois</label>
            <input id="quantidadeCinco" name="mesDois"> <br>

            <label for="mesTres">Quantidade solicitada para o mês tres</label>
            <input id="quantidadeSeis" name="mesTres"> <br>

            <hr>

            <label for="medicamentoTres">Medicamento 03</label>
            <input name="medicamentoTres" name="medicamentoTres"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeUm">Quantidade solicitada para o mês um</label>
            <input id="quantidadeSete" name="quantidadeUm"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeDois">Quantidade solicitada para o mês dois</label>
            <input id="quantidadeOito" name="quantidadeDois"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeTres">Quantidade solicitada para o mês tres</label>
            <input id="quantidadeNove" name="quantidadeTres"> <br>

            <hr>

            <label for="medicamentoQuatro">Medicamento 04</label>
            <input name="medicamentoQuatro" name="medicamentoTres"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeDez">Quantidade solicitada para o mês um</label>
            <input id="quantidadeDez" name="quantidadeDez"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeOnze">Quantidade solicitada para o mês dois</label>
            <input id="quantidadeOnze" name="quantidadeOnze"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeDoze">Quantidade solicitada para o mês tres</label>
            <input id="quantidadeDoze" name="quantidadeDoze"> <br>

            <hr>

            <label for="medicamentoQuinto">Medicamento 05</label>
            <input name="medicamentoQuinto" name="medicamentoTres"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeTreze">Quantidade solicitada para o mês um</label>
            <input id="quantidadeTreze" name="quantidadeTreze"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeCatorze">Quantidade solicitada para o mês dois</label>
            <input id="quantidadeCatorze" name="quantidadeCatorze"> <br>

            <label for="quantidadeQuinze">Quantidade solicitada para o mês tres</label>
            <input id="quantidadeQuinze" name="quantidadeQuinze"> <br>

            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Com ele eu quero preencher um outro arquivo que com o background possua um laudo de medicamentos assim o usuario preenche o form e popula o formulário segue o COD:

```
<?php   
session_start();
include_once $_SESSION[root].$_SESSION[comum]."library/php/db.inc.php";

require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
require_once 'dompdf/lib/html5lib/Parser.php';
require_once 'dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/Autoloader.php';
require_once 'dompdf/lib/php-svg-lib/src/autoload.php';
require_once 'dompdf/src/Autoloader.php';

require_once "barcode.inc.php";
require_once "funcoes.inc.php";

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$html = '';
$html .= <<<'ENDHTML'
<html style="background-image: url(pdf/solicitacaoDeMedicamentos.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;height: 1250px;margin-left: 21%;">

    <style type="text/css">

    .cnes{
            margin-top: 16.8%;
            margin-left: 4%;
            position: absolute;
    }

    </style>
<body>
ENDHTML;
$html .= "<div class='.cnes'>"echo _POST[numeroCNES]"</div>";
$html .= "<div class=''>""</div>";

$html .= "</body></html>";


// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

Mas mesmo o formulário chegando na pagina nada aconteceu apenas o erro 500, eu já testei outros soluções usando o dompdf até exemplos prontos e nada da certo.

Comment: Erro 500 apenas quer dizer que é erro interno do servidor. Por outro lado, seu código possui erros, por exemplo aqui `$html .= "<div class='.cnes'>"echo _POST[numeroCNES]"</div>";` e aqui `$html .= "<div class=''>""</div>";`.

Comment: O estranho que esse mesmo código é usado em outra parte da aplicação , a diferença que na outra parte ele esta usando resultados  de querysSQL

Comment: É impossível o mesmo código estar funcionando em outro trecho do sistema, olha só os erros aqui: https://3v4l.org/kCSi3

Comment: Então é um sistema de mais de 10 anos contendo padrão estrutural e MVC do zend 1.0 tem muita coisa junta .

Comment: Indiferente, é uma questão de sintaxe. A sintaxe está errada, veja: https://3v4l.org/kCSi3 Ocorre erro mesmo na versão `4.3.0`, lançado em 27/12/2002 (quase 16 anos atrás)

Comment: O problema na sintaxe foi encontrado ,ontem mesmo, o correto erá $html .= "<div class='dataSolicitacao'>". $_REQUEST['dataSolicitacao']."</div>";  deve ser informado ."". e algum tipo de request